# Encrypt and decrypt a file from disk rather than memory?

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

When I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a 250MB file using AES algorithm, I am getting the following error. When I am trying with datasets less than 250, I am able to get the output.

[image]

Comment: I heard that reading the file from disk will work rather than reading from memory.Will that Work?If Yes, How do I do that?

Comment: You have not posted the relevant source code. ``std::bad_alloc`` is thrown if ``new`` fails to allocate memory

Comment: FileSource file("C:/Users/sai/desktop/RA/250.avi", true, new StringSink(plain));
 string cipher, encoded, recovered;
 cout << "READ IN DONE" << endl;
 int start_s = clock();*/

Comment: This is how I am reading a file. Do I need to break the file into chunks and then encrypt and decrypt?

Comment: You should show your program, and not a screen shot of the C++ runtime `bad_alloc`.

Answer (score -2):

From the COMMENTS:

```
string cipher, encoded, recovered;
FileSource file("C:/Users/sai/desktop/RA/250.avi", true, new StringSink(plain));
```

This may or may not work depending on several factors. On a desktop or server you should have no problems because it will have a lot of RAM and a swap file.

On a mobile device it will probably die if the file is large. If it dies then the problem is probably because `StringSink` is an in-memory string but the device ran out of memory.

---

From the COMMENTS:

> ... Do I need to break the file into chunks and then encrypt and decrypt?

No, you should not need to break the file into chunks. The `FileSource` will do it for you. It will break the data into 4096 chunks, if I recall correctly. What you probably need to do is switch from a `StringSink` to a `FileSink`.

Also see [Pumping Data | Encryption](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pumping_Data#Encryption) on the Crypto++ wiki. Here's the sample provided:

```
inline bool EndOfFile(const FileSource& file)
{
  std::istream* stream = const_cast<FileSource&>(file).GetStream();
  return stream->eof();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
      byte key[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH]={}, iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE]={};
      CTR_Mode<AES>::Encryption encryptor;
      encryptor.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);

      MeterFilter meter;
      StreamTransformationFilter filter(encryptor);

      FileSource source("plain.bin", false);
      FileSink sink("cipher.bin");

      source.Attach(new Redirector(filter));
      filter.Attach(new Redirector(meter));
      meter.Attach(new Redirector(sink));

      const word64 BLOCK_SIZE = 4096;
      word64 processed = 0;

      while(!EndOfFile(source) && !source.SourceExhausted())
      {
        source.Pump(BLOCK_SIZE);
        filter.Flush(false);

        processed += BLOCK_SIZE;

        if (processed % (1024*1024*10) == 0)
          cout << "Processed: " << meter.GetTotalBytes() << endl;
      }

      // Signal there is no more data to process.
      // The dtor's will do this automatically.
      filter.MessageEnd();
  }
  catch(const Exception& ex)
  {
    cerr << ex.what() << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

From the TITLE:

> [How to] encrypt and decrypt a file from disk rather than memory?

Try something like the following. Your code is missing the encryption or decryption object, so be sure to include one in the real code.

```
FileSource file("C:/Users/sai/desktop/RA/250.avi", true, new FileSink("C:/Users/sai/desktop/RA/250.avi.enc"));
```

Or, you can use the code that shows you how to manually pump data.

---

From the COMMENTS:

```
int start_s = clock();
```

Also see [Benchmarks | Sample Program](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Benchmarks#Sample_Program) on the Crypto++ wiki. Here's the sample provided:

```
const double runTimeInSeconds = 3.0;
const double cpuFreq = 2.7 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

    SecByteBlock key(16);
    prng.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());

    CTR<AES>::Encryption cipher;
    cipher.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), key);

    const int BUF_SIZE = RoundUpToMultipleOf(2048U,
        dynamic_cast<StreamTransformation&>(cipher).OptimalBlockSize());

    AlignedSecByteBlock buf(BUF_SIZE);
    prng.GenerateBlock(buf, buf.size());

    double elapsedTimeInSeconds;
    unsigned long i=0, blocks=1;

    ThreadUserTimer timer;
    timer.StartTimer();

    do
    {
        blocks *= 2;
        for (; i<blocks; i++)
            cipher.ProcessString(buf, BUF_SIZE);
        elapsedTimeInSeconds = timer.ElapsedTimeAsDouble();
    }
    while (elapsedTimeInSeconds < runTimeInSeconds);

    const double bytes = static_cast<double>(BUF_SIZE) * blocks;
    const double ghz = cpuFreq / 1000 / 1000 / 1000;
    const double mbs = bytes / elapsedTimeInSeconds / 1024 / 1024;
    const double cpb = elapsedTimeInSeconds * cpuFreq / bytes;

    std::cout << cipher.AlgorithmName() << " benchmarks..." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  " << ghz << " GHz cpu frequency"  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  " << cpb << " cycles per byte (cpb)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  " << mbs << " MiB per second (MiB)" << std::endl;   

    return 0;
}
```